# Find the boundaries of Signature

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do I find the boundaries of this inverted binary image?
[image]

Comment: just check matlabs tools to work with binary images.

Comment: What do you mean by 'boundaries'?  The bounding box?  The extrema pixels?  The convex hull?

Comment: @Staus Oh sorry I'm a newbie, I mean the bounding box

Comment: Look into `regionprops`. Help yourself with the googling.

Comment: The extent of the signature covers the entire image.  If you were to extract the bounding box, you would essentially get dimensions of the image as a result.  As such, I don't see the point of this question if you can simply just use the dimensions of the image to obtain your answer.

Comment: @rayryeng I want to calculate the signature boundaries from left to right, the first white pixel is the left boundary and the last white pixel is the right boundary, similarly from top to bottom

Comment: alright... I guess I'll toss a bone.  I really shouldn't, but I can't say no to image processing.  FWIW, we aren't a "give me teh codez" site, or "do your homework" site.  You have to show us what you've tried first before asking for help.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that result you've attached, but hopefully it works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are gaps in the signature, using standard bounding box algorithms will fail to fully encapsulate the entire signature because when you detect bounding boxes, the gaps in the strokes will be interpreted as individual regions, and so individual bounding boxes will be detected there.  One work around is to simply find all of those pixels that are non-zero, and find the minimum and maximum row and column locations.  You can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to help you do that.  These minimum and maximum values will correspond to the top left and bottom right corners of the overall bounding box that encapsulates this signature.

Before I show any code, I'm directly reading your image that you have uploaded, but it is a RGB image.  As such, I'm going to convert this to grayscale with [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html), then threshold the image with [`im2bw`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html).  There's also an unnecessary white border around the signature image so I'm going to clear this up with [`imclearborder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html).

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
%// Read in image and convert to binary
%// Also clear the borders
im = imread('http://oi59.tinypic.com/5fk9y0.jpg');
im_bw = imclearborder(im2bw(rgb2gray(im)));

%// Find those non-zero pixel locations
[rows, cols] = find(im_bw);
min_row = min(rows);
max_row = max(rows);
min_col = min(cols);
max_col = max(cols);

%// Now extract the bounding box
bb = im_bw(min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col);

%// Show the image
imshow(bb);
```

When you do this, `bb` should contain the image where the signature is bounded so that it fits within the image exactly.  This is what I get when you display `bb`:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: @rayreng Why my result is like that? OMG sorry to bother you, this is for my thesis, and I'm stuck in here, I want to use this signature before using moment invariant.

Comment: +1 for `can't say no to image processing` haha, that was .. nice to hear!

Comment: @RickiChindra Uh... OK. What just happened? Lol. Are you having a conversation with yourself? You're welcome btw!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case Matlab isn't a firm requirement, or if you wish to check your Matlab results easily, or anyone else is looking who can't afford Matlab, there is the incredibly powerful ImageMagick that runs on all platforms, with command line and bindings for Perl, Python, .NET, Ruby and others.

I increased the borders around your image to make a proper test, and ran the following command:

```
convert out.png -format "%@" info:
362x135+49+26
```

which tells me that the bounding box you seek is 362 pixels wide and 135 pixels tall and its top-left corner is offset 49 pixels right and 26 pixels down from the top-left of the background - all in one simple command.

Just for fun, I can then draw that box in in red with the following command:

```
convert out.png -stroke red -strokewidth 1 -fill none -draw "rectangle 49,26 410,160" box.png
```

so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark :) I actually enjoy reading your answers. imageMagick is so powerful!

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you, Ray. Likewise, I often enjoy your approach and insights on image processing answers.