# Binary Image Matrix

Tags: image, matlab

How to find the matrix value from this signature picture?

[image]

> how to find the matrix value from:
>
> 1. RGB image to Gray Scale
> 2. Gray Scale to Binary Image
> 3. Binary Image to Inverted Binary Image
> 4. Inverted Binary Image with clean border
> 5. Inverted Binary Image with clean border to extract bounding box

I already know the code from RGB to extract bounding box:

```
%// Read in image and convert to binary
%// Also clear the borders
im = imread('http://postimg.org/image/qptg2jgsz/2a2705fb/');
im_bw = imclearborder(im2bw(rgb2gray(im)));

%// Find those non-zero pixel locations
[rows, cols] = find(im_bw);
min_row = min(rows);
max_row = max(rows);
min_col = min(cols);
max_col = max(cols);

%// Now extract the bounding box
bb = im_bw(min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col);

%// Show the image
imshow(bb);
```

Comment: So your question is...?

Comment: I want to know the matriks of the picture

Comment: What does that mean? Also it's matrix with an 'x'

Comment: Nice code!  Looks very familiar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794436/find-the-boundaries-of-signature

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Actually in your code you already have the binary image... BW stands for Black and white...

---

Have you tried the [basic Matlab example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html)?

```
BW = im2bw(I, level);
```

In case you want an automatic choice of threshold level try Otsu's method.

```
level = graythresh(I)
```

Comment: I want to know the matriks of the picture

Comment: @RickiChindra Yeah, that is your question. If you read the few lines of code you have, you can see that you already have calculated it. HAve you tried my suggestion?

Comment: no bro, I want to convert my image to a matrix, I want to use this matrix and calculate it manually and then move to Hu moment invariant

Comment: @RickiChindra Bro do u kno that image is matrx?

Comment: @rayryeng Your comment are making me laugh also XD